# Pass Username and Password for FTP using CMD in Java

Tags: java, ftp

I want to connect through FTP to a Mainframe server. I can't do a direct FTP using prebuilt java libraries. I can open a command prompt and then do the actions though. I tried to automate this and get a java function do this for me. So I created a cmd window in java and connected to the FTP. I am not sure how we can pass the username and password to it.

This is my code for now :

```
public class CMDWindow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start ftp *ip*");
    }    
}
```

And below is what my cmd displays:

```
Connected to *ip*.
Username:
```

How can I pass the username and password to it using java?

Comment: *I can't do a direct FTP using prebuilt java libraries*: Why?

Comment: I am trying to connect to a Mainframe and that doesn't respect the standard java ftp open connection commands that the program sends it but respects the ftp open connection command send using cmd window

Comment: What open connection commands? Should should rather ask how to make the native Java libraries working that to hack it by running command-line `ftp`.